# Windows PSQL command line: is there a way to allow for passwordless login?

Tags: windows, postgresql

My goal is to be able to fire off a command without having to be prompted for my password. Is there any way to achieve this from the windows command line? In Linux I feel I could send the password to standard in or something, but I am not sure if I could do this for windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Set environment variable PGPASSWORD e.g. `set PGPASSWORD=yoursecretpassword`
- Use password file `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` as described in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

Within password file (my location is C:\Users\Grzesiek\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf) use specified in doc format. For example to connect database postgres as role postgres on local 5432 server add:

```
localhost:5432:postgres:postgres:12345
```

I checked this and it works well (for me), but don't use 127.0.0.1).

Comment: @A Question Asker: updated my answer, it should work for file as well

Comment: tell op not to use the -W option if using PGPASSWORD; that's it

Answer (score 14):

Another handy option (specially if your PG server runs in your own client machine, and if this does not poses any security problem for you) is to allow login without password in the server ("trust" authentication mode).

For example, this line in `pg_hba.conf` (in your DATA dir, a typical location: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\data\` ) grants access without password from your local machine.

```
host     all     all     127.0.0.1/32    trust
```

Then, connect with

```
  psql.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -w [YOUR_DB_NAME]
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it is an old question but for anyone looking like I was, it is hard to find a solution for windows.  stick this in a .bat file and it will work (at least for me it did).  change director to postres directory, set environment variable `PGPASSWORD` execute copy command to a csv file and then clear environment variable, then go back to root directory.

```
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\

set PGPASSWORD=yourpassword


psql -d databasename -U yourusername -w -c "\COPY (select * from yourtable) TO 'c:/Users/yourdirectory/yourcsvfilename.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;"

set PGPASSWORD=

cd c:\
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is a bit old now, but I believe there is a better means for secure, password-free PostgreSQL logon on Windows - [SSPI](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Configuring_for_single_sign-on_using_SSPI_on_Windows).

1. Create a local or domain user account and PostgreSQL login with the same name.
2. In `pg_ident.conf`, create a mapping:

   ```
   # MAPNAME   SYSTEM-USERNAME      PG-USERNAME
   SSPI        username@AUTHORITY   loginname
   ```

   Replace *username* with the Windows user name (this is the `sAMAccountName` attribute for domain accounts), and replace *AUTHORITY* with the computer name or short domain name. If you're not sure what to use for *AUTHORITY*, check the PostgreSQL log file. For a local account, this will be the computer name; for a domain account, it's probably the short domain name. Lastly, replace *loginname* with the PostgreSQL login name (to reduce confusion, I would recommend using the same name for both *username* and *loginname*).
3. In `pg_hba.conf`, allow the logon; e.g.:

   ```
   # TYPE   DATABASE   USER        ADDRESS        METHOD
   host     all        loginname   127.0.0.1/32   sspi map=SSPI
   host     all        loginname   ::1/128        sspi map=SSPI
   ```
4. If a domain account, set a SPN for it; e.g.:

   ```
   setspn -S POSTGRES/serverfqdn username
   ```

Now you can log onto Windows using the specified username and run `psql.exe`, etc. without needing a password.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative for those who do not want .pgpass file and want to execute in a single command line instance.

```
set "PGPASSWORD=yourpass" && createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres new_db_name
```

I referred almost every solution related to command line and finally ended by wrapping `"` around PGPASSWORD=yourpass while setting in Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

First ENviroment Var PGPASSWORD

C:\Windows\system32>set PGPASSWORD=clave

before

psql -d basededatos -U usuario

Ready,

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in Postgres 15 with:

```sql
psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -p 54322 -f some_file password=postgres
```

J

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use Powershell, you can set environment variables inline, similar to bash.

This should work:

```
$Env:PGPASSWORD='your-pass'; psql -U postgres
```

Note the semicolon between setting the variable and actual command, this is important since those are inline but two separate commands.

Answer (score -3):

I found another useful solution that worked for me on [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/how-to-use-psql-with-no-password-prompt). It basically sets the `PGPASSWORD` at the beginning of your command like this:

```
PGPASSWORD=PASSWORD psql YOUR_CODE
```

Comment: That works in bash, but not the windows command line.