# Postgresql: Scripting psql execution with password

Tags: postgresql, psql

How can I call **psql** so that it **doesn't prompt for a password**?

This is what I have:

```
psql -Umyuser < myscript.sql
```

However, I couldn't find the argument that passes the password, and so psql always prompts for it.

Comment: I ended up going for the PGPASSWORD environment variable. This fitted my usecase perfectly. Simple and self-contained in the script.

Comment: Just found this http://postgresguide.com/utilities/psql.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify a password to psql non-interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively)

Answer (score 524, accepted):

You may wish to read a summary of [the ways to authenticate to PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html).

To answer your question, there are several ways provide a password for password-based authentication:

1. **Via the password prompt**. Example:

   ```
   psql -h uta.biocommons.org -U foo
   Password for user foo:
   ```
2. **In a pgpass file**. See [libpq-pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html). Format:

   ```
   <host>:<port>:<database>:<user>:<password>
   ```
3. **With the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable**. See [libpq-envars](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html). Example:

   ```
   export PGPASSWORD=yourpass
   psql ...

   # Or in one line for this invocation only:
   PGPASSWORD=yourpass psql ...
   ```
4. **In the connection string** The password and other options may be specified in the connection string/URI. See  [app-psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). Example:

   ```
   psql postgresql://username:password@dbmaster:5433/mydb?sslmode=require
   ```

Comment: I think PGPASSWORD is deprecated but still works, btw.  Just FYI

Comment: Yep, it's deprecated (and so noted in one of the links).  Since it's come up, it's probably also worth noting that the deprecation is hotly contested because it's extremely useful for many people yet can be used in some circumstances without serious security concerns. It seems to me that it's no worse than storing .pgpass on an NFS filesystem, for example. I use PGPASSWORD routinely.

Comment: the idea that command line information is "available to all users" is based on antiquated assumptions about multi-user systems and does not apply in most modern environments where systems just run a single application and it's all automated

Comment: "There is no option to provide the password as a command line argument" is false, as you'll find in another answer  (using a URI).

Comment: Fast Forward 2021: For anyone using Postgresql version 13 -  `PGPASSWORD=yourpass psql ...` doesn't seem to work with version 13 anymore (on Debian 10 in my case), therefore I successfully did with the connection string as explained in the [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/)

Comment: Works for me. `psql (PostgreSQL) 13.2` on a Mac.

Comment: The `PGPASSWORD` environment variable is documented for Postgres 13 and 14 - see [doc page for 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq-envars.html)

Comment: With the connection string it looks like it is impossible to output the results of the sql command.

Comment: For those folks who are looking for this answer in the Windows Environment (as I was), `set PGPASSWORD=Password` works great with Postgres - we are running version 15!

Answer (score 196):

```
PGPASSWORD=[your password] psql -Umyuser < myscript.sql
```

Comment: this works in terraform as well. you, my friend, are a lifesaver

Answer (score 83):

You can add this command line at the beginning of your script:

```
export PGPASSWORD="[your password]"
```

Comment: in my case set command did not work but `export PGPASSWORD=[password]` did work

Comment: it does not work in shell script. I am using it 
`#!/bin/sh
set PGPASSWORD = postgres
psql -h 192.168.3.200 -U postgres incx_um << EOF
DELETE FROM usrmgt.user_one_time_codes WHERE time < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 minute'
EOF`

Comment: Try not using spaces, eg. `PGPASSWORD=password`.

Answer (score 59):

If you intend on having multiple hosts/database connections, the [~/.pgpass file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html) is the way to go.

Steps:

1. Create the file using `vim ~/.pgpass` or similar. Input your information in the following format:
   `hostname:port:database:username:password` Do not add string quotes around your field values. You can also use * as a wildcard for your port/database fields.
2. You must `chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass` in order for it to not be silently ignored by psql.
3. Create an alias in your bash profile that runs your psql command for you. For example:`alias postygresy='psql --host hostname database_name -U username'` The values should match those that you inputted to the ~/.pgpass file.
4. Source your bash profile with `. ~/.bashrc` or similar.
5. Type your alias from the command line.

Note that if you have an export PGPASSWORD='' variable set, it will take precedence over the file.

Comment: You must do a `chmod 600` on the file, otherwise `psql` will silently ignore it (according to the docs).

Comment: This may not be such a good solution on Windows servers, where many things run with users without a user directory.

Answer (score 59):

This might be an old question, but there's an alternate method you can use that no one has mentioned. It's possible to specify the password directly in the connection URI. The documentation can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html), alternatively [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-connect.html).

You can provide your username and password directly in the connection URI provided to `psql`:

```
# postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]
psql postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/mydb
```

Comment: Postrgres 9.3 ignores environment variable `PGPASSWORD`

Comment: It may need to quote the argument for it to work: `psql.exe "postgresql://username:password@address:5432/database"`

Answer (score 22):

An alternative to using `PGPASSWORD` environment variable is to use `conninfo` string according to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-psql.html)

> An alternative way to specify connection parameters is in a conninfo
>   string or a URI, which is used instead of a database name. This
>   mechanism give you very wide control over the connection.

```
$ psql "host=<server> port=5432 dbname=<db> user=<user> password=<password>"

postgres=>
```

Comment: This is good for sanity testing other methods aren't working. Besides, keeping the password out of your shell history can be as simple as [putting a space before a command](https://digi.ninja/blog/hiding_bash_history.php).

Answer (score 13):

You have to create a password file: see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html for more info.

Answer (score 13):

If you're having problems on windows like me (I'm using Windows 7 64-bit) and `set PGPASSWORD=[Password]` did not work.

Then, as Kavaklioglu said in one of the comments,

```
export PGPASSWORD=[password]
```

You will need to save this at the top of the file, or before any usage so its set before being called.

Certainly does work on windows :)

Comment: `export PGPASSWORD=[password]` does not work for me  using the command line (cmd.exe) at all. Are you sure you weren't using cygwin or something similar?

Comment: Only works with cl, you added it to the file right? Now just typed it into command?

Comment: it's ok to use it in linux/mac environment, for windows, i think you should find a way to export this environment variable.

Comment: So add a global password... Thats a interesting idea as well

Answer (score 8):

Given the security concerns about using the PGPASSWORD environment variable, I think the best overall solution is as follows:

1. Write your own temporary pgpass file with the password you want to use.
2. Use the PGPASSFILE environment variable to tell psql to use that file.
3. Remove the temporary pgpass file

There are a couple points of note here.  Step 1 is there to avoid mucking with the user's ~/.pgpass file that might exist.  You also must make sure that the file has permissions 0600 or less.

Some have suggested leveraging bash to shortcut this as follows:

```
PGPASSFILE=<(echo myserver:5432:mydb:jdoe:password) psql -h myserver -U jdoe -p 5432 mydb
```

This uses the <() syntax to avoid needing to write the data to an actual file.  But it doesn't work because psql checks what file is being used and will throw an error like this:

```
WARNING: password file "/dev/fd/63" is not a plain file
```

Comment: A working example of this approach appears in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40614592/3696363 - another answer to this question.

Comment: Although this user didn't really ask for the same thing I'm looking for, I would say that the approach doesn't match.

When using the PGPASSFILE=<(whatever) syntax, you can do things like decrypt a file and only have it present in the file descriptor that is created. By writing a temp file, you're not fundamentally solving the problem of having a file on disk with credentials.

It's not fun dealing with arbitrary industry rules like that, but it's a thing many people deal with.

Answer (score 8):

It can be done simply using PGPASSWORD. I am using psql 9.5.10. In your case the solution would be

`PGPASSWORD=password psql -U myuser < myscript.sql`

Answer (score 5):

Building on [mightybyte's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27321600/3696363) for those who aren't comfortable with **nix* shell scripting, here's a working script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PGPASSFILE=/tmp/pgpasswd$$
touch $PGPASSFILE
chmod 600 $PGPASSFILE
echo "myserver:5432:mydb:jdoe:password" > $PGPASSFILE
export PGPASSFILE
psql mydb
rm $PGPASSFILE
```

The double dollar sign (`$$`) in `/tmp/pgpasswd$$` at line 2 appends the process ID number to the file name, so that this script can be run more than once, even simultaneously, without side effects.

Note the use of the `chmod` command at line 4 - just like the "*not a plain file*" error that **mightybyte** described, there's also a "*permissions*" error if this is not done.

At line 7, you won't have to use the `-h`*myserver*, the `-p`*myport*, or `-U`*jdoe* flag if you use the defaults (*localhost* : *5432*) and only have one database user.  For multiple users, (but the default connection) change that line to

```
psql mydb jdoe
```

Don't forget to make the script *executable* with

> `chmod +x runpsql` (*or whatever you called the script file*)

**UPDATE:**

I took **RichVel**'s advice and made the file unreadable *before* putting the password into it.  That closes a slight security hole.
Thanks!

Comment: You can use [`mktemp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mktemp) to create a temporary file instead of coming up with your own naming scheme.
It creates a new temp file (named something like `/tmp/tmp.ITXUNYgiNh` in Linux and `/var/folders/xx/7gws2yy91vn9_t2lb8jcr2gr0000gn/T/tmp.QmbVOQk4` on MacOS X) and prints its name to stdout.

Comment: **Security issue** It's best to do the `chmod 600` after creating the file, but before writing the password to it.  As written, a malicious script on the server could continually try to read files of this format, and would sometimes succeed in getting the password.  Also, if this script is interrupted for some reason, the file would be left on disk - writing a shell `trap` handler would address this.  Given that it's not trivial to write a secure script like this, I recommend using `export PGPASSWORD` instead.

Comment: Thanks, @RichVel for pointing out that small security hole. _Touch_ creating and making the file private before putting the password in it is a definite improvement.  
This kind of solution is needed because `PGPASSWORD` has been deprecated in 9.3.

Comment: Some of the docs say it's deprecated but as mentioned in a comment in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523019/postgresql-scripting-psql-execution-with-password), the deprecation is contested and it still works as of Postgres 10.6

Comment: create the file in your home directory, mkdir ~/.creds; touch ~/.creds/pgpass$$ && chmod 0600 ~/.creds/pgpass$$

Answer (score 2):

You may find this useful: [Windows PSQL command line: is there a way to allow for passwordless login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216432/windows-psql-command-line-is-there-a-way-to-allow-for-passwordless-login)

Answer (score 2):

8 years later...

On my mac, I had to put a line into the file
`~/.pgpass` like:

```
<IP>:<PORT>:<dbname>:<user>:<password>
```

Also see:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpass

Comment: Don't use -W for psql  if you use .pgpass. This parameter cancel .pgpass usage.

Comment: Also ensure permissions `u=rw` for that file.

Answer (score 1):

This also works for other postgresql clis for example you can run pgbench in non-interactive mode.

```
export PGPASSWORD=yourpassword
/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/pgbench -h $REMOTE_PG_HOST -p 5432 -U postgres -c 12 -j 4 -t 10000 example > pgbench.out 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows worked the combination of url string and using psql options:

```
> psql -d postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/mydb -f myscript.sql
```

passing the the command without -d was not working, just connected to the database, but no execution of the script

Comment: On Ubuntu worked too!

Answer (score -1):

I find, that psql show password prompt even you define PGPASSWORD variable, but you can specify -w option for psql to omit password prompt.

Answer (score -6):

Use -w in the command:
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user -w