# import .sql file in postgres using \i command from java

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to import database from .sql file in postgres using "\i E:/dump.sql" command , its working fine from postgres command prompt but when i try the same from java it raise an error at "\" , my code is

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database","postgres", "passwd");
PreparedStatement ps3 = connection.prepareStatement("\\i E:/dump.sql");
boolean res3= ps3.execute();
System.out.println("imported succesfully .."+res3);
```

Answer (score 3):

With the JDBC driver/interface you can only talk SQL, what you're trying is to issue PostgreSQL commandline tool (`psql`) specific commands. That won't work.

If you insist on doing this, you could use the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` approach, something like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "psql -f dump.sql" );
```

Cheers,

Comment: thanks for the answer , how i can do the same with Runtime.getRuntime().exec() ..can you please elaborate it.

Comment: Here on Stackoverflow you are expected to show some effort yourself. There are tons of resources on this matter here and elsewhere.

Comment: it doesn't work dude , becoz with "psql -f dump.sql" it will prompt you for password . how i would provide that ? .. ok . i will be managing that using ProcessBuilder and its environment() method . but still its raising error path specified not found . just stucked!

Comment: Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523019/postgresql-scripting-psql-execution-with-password) or setup trust in `pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Long story short - you can't. `\i` is not PostgreSQL command (as in: PostgreSQL database engine). It's command of `psql` - which is command line tool for interacting with database.

If you're connecting to database via JDBC you're not using psql, so you can't use its commands (`\i`, `\o` and alike).

Comment: sure, open the file, read ot, oarse into separate queries, and send them to pg. or use psql, like Anders suggested.