# Executing PSQL in R on Windows

Tags: windows, r, postgresql, psql, greenplum

I have been trying to execute PSQL from system() within R in RStudio. I have PSQL setup in my PATH and can execute PSQL from the cmd line. I cannot for the life of me figure out the correct method for executing psql from within R on windows. I have code supplied from a ubuntu environment. I have not used system() previously before this and researching for this specific issue has been unsuccessful.

The hardest part is not receiving any output after executing system in R. I have tried a few different setting from looking at ?system. With no luck.

This code should execute a simple sql statement and pass the output to a local file. Ultimately this will be more robust to include dynamic elements in an application. Just having the basics working seems like the hardest part.

```
system(paste("export PGPASSWORD=db_password;psql -h db_host -d db_name -c 'copy(select * from large_table limit 1000) to stdout csv' > C:/temp_data/db_test.dat", sep=""))
```

I am curious as to if anyone has a working windows environment using PSQL in R. My greenplum server is not local.

My echo %PATH% includes C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.12
included in both system and user vars.

Comment: I simplified the string in paste for my question so it may look strange using paste with one string.

Comment: `export` isn't a command on Windows. You probably want `set`.

Comment: You can also set the password [for `postgres` or other user] using [the pgpass file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html). This can be [set up with pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pg/libpq-pgpass.html). [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523019/postgresql-scripting-psql-execution-with-password).

Comment: Note that your pgAdmin is ancient.

Comment: @nograpes Wouldn't think the pgAdmin version matters much when the db version is 8.2.15. Would the most recent be more efficient for older versions?

Comment: It is actually your `psql` version that matters, but I assume that pgAdmin comes with a version of `psql`? Your db is also old, so I guess it is okay to use an old `psql`. I'm not sure if there will be any efficiency changes if you move to a new `psql`. There might be bug fixes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your command.

- `system` cannot be used with redirects, you must use `shell`
- You cannot use single quotes to quote commands in Windows, you must    use double quotes.
- To concatenate commands, you use the `&` operator, not a `;` like in    Unix.

So your command would look like (it appears to be necessary to include this in one line):

```
cmd<-'set PGPASSWORD=db_password& psql -h db_host -d db_name -c "copy(select * from large_table limit 1000) TO STDOUT CSV;" > C:/temp_data/db_test.dat'
shell(cmd)
```

But, have you considered using the `RPostgresql` driver, which is a much simpler, platform-independent way to do your task?

```r
# Load up the driver
library(RPGsql)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
# Create a connection
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="db_name", host='db_host',password='db_password',user='db_user')
# Query the database
db_test=dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from large_table limit 1000')
# Write your file
write.csv(db_test,'C:/temp_data/db_test.dat')
```

Comment: Yes I considered RPostgresql and have used PivotalR since greenplum is build on top of pivotal.  The reason I'm trying this method is for pushing data into tables. There are certain limitations for security reasons. I have a 30min window for this process. I heard that psql is the preferred way to do this. Just need a good test case to benchmark.

Comment: Hm, it sounds like you have a good reason for doing it this way. Did you try the command `cmd` that I provided? Did it work the way you expected?

Comment: If you want to write data to the database, RPostgreSQL provides a `dbWriteTable` function for that as well.

Comment: The shell execution works perfectly up until: > C:/temp_data/db_test.dat

This line doesnt seem to have any effect or execute. The results are posted to the console. Does the output of a shell require special method to save to file or the R environment in general?

Comment: @dotcomken The redirection works on my machine. I think I know what is happening: put the `cmd<-...` on one line, it appears that R is parsing the `\n`s and passing them along to `shell`, which doesn't work.

Comment: Adding all to a single line worked perfectly. Thanks again for your help.