# Loading PostgreSQL Database Backup Into Docker/Initial Docker Data

Tags: postgresql, backup, docker

I am migrating an application into Docker.  One of the issues that I am bumping into is what is the correct way to load the initial data into PostgreSQL running in Docker? My typical method of restoring a database backup file are not working.  I have tried the following ways:

`gunzip -c mydbbackup.sql.gz | psql -h <docker_host> -p <docker_port> -U <dbuser> -d <db> -W`

That does not work, because PostgreSQL is prompting for a password, and I cannot enter a password because it is reading data from STDOUT.  I cannot use the $PGPASSWORD environment variable, because the any environment variable I set in my host is not set in my container.

I also tried a similar command above, except using the -f flag, and specify the path to a sql backup file.  This does not work because my file is not on my container.  I could copy the file to my container with the ADD statement in my Dockerfile, but this does not seem right.

So, I ask the community.  What is the preferred method on loading PostgreSQL database backups into Docker containers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with persistent storage (e.g. databases) in docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker)

Comment: See also https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/ AND http://docs.docker.com/examples/postgresql_service/

Comment: I have read the articles that you referenced.  The scenerio I am asking about is:  I have a PostgreSQL database in a container and a separate data container.  Both containers are running, the database is emtpy.  I have a backup file located on my host.  How do I go about restoring the file into the empty database?  My question above described what I have tried and the problems I have run into.  I could bake the backup file into the data container, but that does not seem right.

Comment: Ahhh wrong duplicate so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523019/postgresql-scripting-psql-execution-with-password and another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively

Comment: The links refer to using a $PGPASSWORD environment variable or a ./pgpass file.  Is that a secure solution to bake either an environment variable or a text file into a container with a plain text password in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot use the $PGPASSWORD environment variable, because the any
>   environment variable I set in my host is not set in my container.

I don't use docker, but your container looks like a remote host in the command shown, with `psql` running locally.  So `PGPASSWORD` never has to to be set on the remote host, only locally.

If the problems boils down to adding a password to this command:

```
gunzip -c mydbbackup.sql.gz |
  psql -h <docker_host> -p <docker_port> -U <dbuser> -d <db> -W
```

you may submit it using several methods (in all cases, don't use the `-W` option to psql)

- hardcoded in the invocation:

  ```
   gunzip -c mydbbackup.sql.gz |
    PGPASSWORD=something psql -h <docker_host> -p <docker_port> -U <dbuser> -d <db>
  ```
- typed on the keyboard

  ```
   echo -n "Enter password:"
   read -s PGPASSWORD
   export PGPASSWORD
   gunzip -c mydbbackup.sql.gz |
     psql -h <docker_host> -p <docker_port> -U <dbuser> -d <db>
  ```

**Note about the `-W` or `--password` option to psql.**

The point of this option is to ask for a password to be typed first thing, even if the context makes it unnecessary.

It's frequently misunderstood as the equivalent of the `-p`option of mysql. This is a mistake: while `-p` is required on password-protected connections, `-W` is never required and actually goes in the way when scripting.

```
       -W, --password
           Force psql to prompt for a password before connecting to a
           database.

           This option is never essential, since psql will automatically
           prompt for a password if the server demands password
           authentication. However, psql will waste a connection attempt
           finding out that the server wants a password. In some cases it is
           worth typing -W to avoid the extra connection attempt.
```