# "psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied" when running postgres as a Docker service

Tags: python, bash, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run the following a Docker Compose multi-container application with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=iperuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=iperpassword
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/apks
      - POSTGRES_DB=iper_apks

  alchemy:
    build: ./alchemy
    environment:
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGPORT=5432
      - PGUSER=iperuser
    links:
      - postgres
```

I would like to the `alchemy` service to wait for `postgres` to be ready to accept commands using the `wait-for-postgres.sh` script at https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/:

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait-for-postgres.sh
# From https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

The `Dockerfile` for the `alchemy` service is

```
FROM python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes postgresql
RUN pip install sqlalchemy psycopg2
COPY . /alchemy
WORKDIR alchemy
RUN chmod +x wait-for-postgres.sh
CMD ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "postgres", "python", "apk_tables.py"]
```

where I'm using the hostname `postgres`, since this is the name of the service corresponding to the `postgres` Docker image. The problem is that if I `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up`, I get the following logs:

```
Starting apkapi_postgres_1
Recreating apkapi_alchemy_1
Attaching to apkapi_postgres_1, apkapi_alchemy_1
postgres_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-26 17:22:32 UTC
alchemy_1   | Password for user postgres: 
postgres_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
alchemy_1   | psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
postgres_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
alchemy_1   | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
postgres_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
alchemy_1   | Password for user postgres: 
alchemy_1   | psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
alchemy_1   | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
alchemy_1   | Password for user postgres: 
alchemy_1   | psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
alchemy_1   | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
```

which keeps going on forever.

What I suspect is that the `wait-for-postgres.sh` assumes that PostgreSQL is running on the local host, which is trusted, whereas a database running on a different host requires a password. Is this the case? If so, how can I modify the script to make it use a password (which in this case I suppose would be `iperpassword`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you simply need to pass the password into the `psql` command in order for it to be able to present the password that your remote host requires. The following question gives the options for achieving that: [Postgresql: Scripting psql execution with password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523019/postgresql-scripting-psql-execution-with-password)

Comment: Yes, in the end I added a `PGPASSWORD=iperpassword` line to the `environment` of the `alchemy` service.