# How to create tables in postgresql db instance on gcp through Terraform?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have created postgresql instance (with db and users) and successfully deployed on Google cloud platform. Can someone please suggest how can I create tables in this db through Terraform?

Comment: My Opinion: Terraform is designed for the infrastructure, not for the soft part. I recommend you to look at something else, like Ansible more suitable for that.

Comment: I agree. Use the correct tool for the task. Using Terraform for non-infrastructure tasks via hooks and hacks will one day result in Terraform recreating something and then you will have data loss.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html), something along the lines of:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "default" {
  [...]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "PGPASSWORD=<password> psql -f schema.sql -p <port> -U <username> <databasename>"
  }
}
```

`schema.sql` would hold your table definitions.

Caveats: `psql` must be installed on the database server and you need to provide the password to the command, see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523019/postgresql-scripting-psql-execution-with-password).

Comment: On GCP i have already created a postgresql instance and a database. I also installed postgresql on my local and set path varibales as well but while running the above script in terraform throws error.

 'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 0):

follow the different steps in Github , here i terraform module for Postgresql
https://github.com/cyrilgdn/terraform-provider-postgresql