# C# Winforms: Answering output of a command issued using cmd.exe in a process

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms, command-prompt

I am designing a winforms application to save some stuffs in PostgreSQL. In one part of my code I have  to perform some PostgreSQL works like moving a table (named as `serialnumbers`) from one database (named as `firstcards`) to another (named as `secondcards`) and I have to use command prompt "cmd.exe" for the whole process.

**The problem is;** After sending a command to take the backup of table, I couldn't enter my db password to output of that command and thats why I couldn't go further to perform table transfer.

I checked [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216432/windows-psql-command-line-is-there-a-way-to-allow-for-passwordless-login) but actually what I want to learn is to perform tasks by answering the output of commands.

My code is:

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd\\ && cd program files\\postgresql\\10\\bin && pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -Fc -b -v -t public.serialnumbers -f \"C:\\Users\\aetaser\\Desktop\\old\\table.backup\" firstcards"); // after sending this command, it returns an output to enter password
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("1");// my db password
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd\\ && cd program files\\postgresql\\10\\bin && pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -v -d secondcards \"C:\\Users\\aetaser\\Desktop\\old\\table.backup\""); 
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("1"); 
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
```

Comment: I checked that topic but actually what i want to learn is to perform tasks by answering the output of commands.