# Nodejs - Trying to execute postgre sql file

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, node-pg-pool

I'm trying to run the following command via nodejs:

`psql -U postgres -d dbName -f import.sql`

But I got the following prompt in the console:

> Password for user postgres:

I tried to set the password via environnment variable, like this:

`SET PGPASSWORD=mypassword && psql -U postgres -d dbName -f import.sql`

But for some reason I get the following error:

> psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

I tripled check and it is the correct password, I also tried to change the password to use something without any special characters, suspecting an encoding issue, but still fails.

Then I tried with `node-postgres`, like this:

```js
const file = (await readFile("./download/import.sql")).toString();

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "dbName",
  password: "myPassword",
  port: 5432,
});

await pool.query(file);
```

But it fails because my script contains lines like this: `\copy tableA from 'db/tableA'` and I have no idea how to solve this.

Next, I tried with `spawn`, like this:

```js
const child = spawn("psql", ["-h", "localhost", "-U", "postgres", "-d", "dbName", "-f", "./download/import.sql"]);

child.stdin.write("myPassword");
child.stdin.end();
```

But I can still see the prompt asking for a password.

I'm running out of idea

EDIT:
I'm using Windows

Comment: 1) This `psql -U postgres -d dbName -f import.sql` is not `nodejs` it is  a command line client for Postgres. 2) This `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"` means you are using the wrong password. 3) This `\copy tableA from 'db/tableA'` fails because `\copy` is a meta-command only understood by the `psql` client. 4) To your question text add  a) Postgres version b) The contents of your `pg_hba.conf` file starting at the line *# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD*

Comment: It looks like you need to find the password specifically for the user postgres as set in your Postgres, and supply it when you run the Postgres command.

Comment: Look in the server's log file.  There are reasons password authentication can fail other than the wrong password, but the unauthenticated client won't be given the details on that.

Comment: Also shouldn't this be `export PGPASSWORD=mypassword`?

Comment: I'm on Windows, I have upldated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

It works if I use the connection string to connect:

```js
execSync(`psql -f ./download/import.sql "postgresql://postgres:myPassword@localhost/dbName"`);
```

Here is the format:
`postgresql://<username>:<password>@<server>/<db>`

Answer (score 0):

Postgres / libpq has a feature that allows you to put the credentials used by psql in a specific ".pgpass" file

cf https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

this could help you at the price of creating a file with specific user rights on the filesystem.

Depending on the project and the security needed around the credentials, I advise you to

- create the file before usage, and remove after the psql operation is finished
- create a specific postgres role/user for this task with constrained rights. this user could be created / deleted before and after the operation

Note what the documentation says otherwise it will not work:

> On Unix systems, the permissions on a password file must disallow any
> access to world or group; achieve this by a command such as chmod 0600
> ~/.pgpass. If the permissions are less strict than this, the file will
> be ignored. On Microsoft Windows, it is assumed that the file is
> stored in a directory that is secure, so no special permissions check
> is made.

Comment: This really does not apply to the question as the issue there is that the password being supplied is incorrect. Putting an incorrect password in `.pgpass` will not magically solve that issue.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver I agree it can be a pg_hba.conf problem but I considered that he knows the correct password and that entering the password at the prompt was leading to a correct import.

Answer (score 0):

If the password you are using is correct and the psql command works when you enter the password at the prompt, maybe the problem is with the PGPASSWORD not beeing correctly set.

on the command line, try (no SET, no &&):

PGPASSWORD='mypassword' psql -U postgres -d dbName -f import.sql

this is the usual way for me to pass a tmp env variable to a script. This could need some more escaping if you have single quotes in your password.

Comment: Already tried this, didn't work either :/ I guess you are on Linux? I'm on Windows

Comment: yes I don't have a solution for windows. If you want to use something different than the connection string solution you found, there is a discussion on this topic on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216432/windows-psql-command-line-is-there-a-way-to-allow-for-passwordless-login